# Meteor - Setting Session variables in Asynchronous Calls

Tags: function, session, asynchronous, callback, meteor

I have a problem with setting session variables inside of a Meteor.call function. It appears that Meteor won't set the session variables to whatever I ask it outside of the scope of the function.

```js
Meteor.startup(function () {
  // code to run on server at startup
  // prompt for name

  var playerName = prompt("Please enter your name:", "");
  Meteor.call('createPlayer', playerName, function(error, result) {
    console.log("PLAYER_ID: " + result);
    Session.set("myPlayerID", result);
    console.log("SESSION_PLAYER_ID: " + Session.get("myPlayerID"));
  });

  console.log("SESSION_PLAYER_ID2: " + Session.get("myPlayerID"));
  Session.set("gameState", SHOW_LOBBY);
});
```

The console prints out:

PLAYER_ID: correct ID

SESSION_PLAYER_ID: correct ID

SESSION_PLAYER_ID2: undefined

As you can see, the session variable is no longer correct outside of the scope of the function. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `createPlayer` is asynchronous, so the order of execution will be:

1. prompt the user
2. **start** the call to `createPlayer`
3. log `myPlayerID` session variable (SESSION_PLAYER_ID2)
4. **finsh** the call to `createPlayer`: set the `myPlayerID` session variable in the callback

Because (4) will execute after (3), you will get `undefined` when trying to log "SESSION_PLAYER_ID2". If that's the only thing going on (i.e. there isn't a bug somewhere else in your code), you should be able to do the following in your browser console:

```
console.log(Session.get('myPlayerID'));
```

And, hopefully, you will get the correct result. So to answer your original question: I don't see anything wrong here - the Session variable will still be available outside of the scope. This appears to be just a misunderstanding of the behavior of asynchronous functions.