# Cannot use variable returned from method call()

Tags: meteor

Why is it that when I do Meteor.call() on a method with a CALLBACK, the result variable contains what I'm looking for while it's inside the callback, yet when I try to use that retrieved variable from callback, it returns undefined!?!?

How do you retrieve a variable from a Meteor.method and actually use it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Meteor - Setting Session variables in Asynchronous Calls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23178187/meteor-setting-session-variables-in-asynchronous-calls)

Comment: can you show some code? I'm not clear what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use either **Session** or **Collection**, You can set the Session variable from the callback method OR Store the data to collection and use that collection to show them on the client-side